# How to cite my advisor on my own thesis?

Tags: citations, thesis, advisor, ethics, undergraduate

There is one section inside a chapter of my thesis that ended up written by my advisor.

As it stands right now, I think it should have quotation marks, and then to add the reference from where it's from.  But  it's from my advisor, not a paper, book, etc. How can I cite my advisor properly?

Could be something like: advisor's name, university, department, year? or how?

Or to add a footnote, explaining that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The direction of the verbs is confusing. How did it end up in your advisors work, but you are asking how to cite it in *your work*. What does it mean to be "from" your advisor?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- got it, I edited it

Comment: So your advisor wrote some words, and then you just inserted it wholesale into your thesis? Words can't just "end up" in a thesis haha

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- That's correct. I actually wrote the section, but then my advisor said, in short, "remove all that, I'll help you there" The thing is that, all that I wrote went away :/ and what my advisor wrote, took its place.

Comment: That is... unusual. Have you asked your advisor how you are supposed to treat the text?

Comment: If you mean that your advisor wrote a part of your thesis you don't have to take any formal action as far the thesis itself is concerned. Whatever one can think of it, this is kind of supervisor discussing with you etc. Nobody else knows. Of course the advisor would be a acknowledged the proper way independent of this. That is your thesis, the advisor just helped you for whatever reasons (perhaps s/he think having wrote a perfect paragraph / section.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing when the work of another is included isn't the actual literal quote marks, but the extent of what is included. This can be done a number of ways and, of course, requires that copyrights are honored.

But, in a work of mathematics, one can state a theorem and then say the following proof is by A. Mathematician (i.e. the name). The delimiters of the quote aren't quote marks but Proof:...QED.

You can also give a reason why the other person's work is included rather than your own. In one case there were two proofs available, one by the author and the other by the advisor. But the advisor's proof offered some additional insight so was preferred for publication. In this case, the proof hadn't previously appeared (nor the theorem itself).

Make the extent clear to avoid plagiarism and make sure that copyright is observed as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think that at some point in the thesis you acknowledge your advisor's direct contribution with words like

> The ideas in Section/Chapter whatever are due to [your advisor's
> name].

or

> The proof of Theorem whatever is due to [your advisor's name].

Discuss with your advisor just where and how you say that.

Of course  you acknowledge their generous help in general as well.